# Cannot Preview SSRS reports - Embedded connection

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

I cannot preview reports when using any embedded DS connection. I can however preview reports if I switch to 'Shared' DS connections.

I am on Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.5

Any ideas why?

[image]

Embedded Data Source Configuration is given below.

[image: EmbeddedDataSourceConfiguration]

Answer (score 0):

Check with the credentials under data source properties 
Can you attach a screenshot for the following issue ,so that we can get an exact solution to your problem